Exponential Rate Analog of Berry-Esseen.
The Berry-Esseen theorem is as follows:
Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ be i.i.d. random variables with mean $\mu$, variance $\sigma^2 > 0$, and third absolute moment $\rho = \mathbb{E}[|X_1 - \mu|^3] < \infty$. Define the standardized sum $S_n$ as
$$
S_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \mu).
$$
Then, there exists a universal constant $C$ such that
$$
\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \left| \mathbb{P}\left( \frac{S_n}{\sigma} \leq x \right) - \Phi(x) \right| \leq \frac{C \rho}{\sigma^3 \sqrt{n}},
$$
where $\Phi(x)$ is the CDF of the standard Gaussian.
I am wondering whether there is an analog of this theorem that has an exponential rate. That is, instead of the bound being $\mathcal{O}(1/\sqrt{n})$, I would like it to be $2^{-\mathcal{O}(n)}$. Obviously this will require much stronger assumptions, but it seems plausible given that the standard Berry-Esseen theorem only uses third moments.
